# JPA annotation for MS SQL Server 2008 R2 IDENTITY column

Tags: hibernate, sql-server-2008, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to know proper JPA annotation setup to handle MS Server 2008 R2 IDENTITY column.

MS Server 2008 R2 (RTM) doesn't support SEQUENCE, but the IDENTITY gives auto increment when I tested by raw sql.

However, by JPA I can't make it work by any strategy (IDENTITY, AUTO, TABLE) on @GeneratedValue annotation and I'm not allowed to change DB schema, since it is others. I didn't try with SEQUENCE, because of there is no sequence.

**DB Table Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[invoice_header](
    [invoice_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ApprovalDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ApproverUserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_invoice_header] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [invoice_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**JPA Annotation**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice_header")
public class InvoiceHeader {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Column(name="invoice_id")
    private Long invoiceId;
```

**Hibernate Error**

```
Hibernate: insert into tbl_acct_textura_invoice_header (invoice_id, ApprovalDate, ApproverUserName) values (null, ?, ?)
2015-06-16 11:12:24.149 ERROR 7157 --- [tp1024240671-18] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
```

It failed because of passing null on the Id. I could make HQL not include invoice_id column during insert by insertable=false and updatable=false on @Column annotation, but then hibernate wasn't happy about not including Id column like below. Any suggestion? FYI, I'm using spring-data JpaRepository

**Hibernate Error when not include the id column during insert**

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): ...InvoiceHeader
```

Comment: IDENTITY database fields should use "IDENTITY" strategy, that is what it is for, and works with DataNucleus when I've tried it. If Hibernate doesn't with that then report a bug against them or find a more recent version

Comment: Thank you Neil for your suggestion, but I found I missed setting dialect on LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found I missed setting up hibernate dialect on LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean. After setting up org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect as hibernate dialect, the GenerationType.IDENTITY works fine as Neil mentioned.

Below is my spring data configuration and application.properties. 
FYI I have multiple datasource, one is H2 embedded datasource for internal use and the other is MS SQL 2008 server for remote data access which I had issue on.

**Spring Data Configuration for MS SQL 2008 server**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "adapterEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "adapterTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.textura.client.erp.database.repository"})
public class ErpRepositoryConfig {
    @Autowired
    JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;

    @Value("${adapter.datasource.url}")
    private String databaseUrl;

    @Value("${adapter.datasource.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${adapter.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${adapter.datasource.hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;

    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new DriverManagerDataSource(databaseUrl, username, password);
    }
    @Bean(name = "adapterEntityManager")
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean(name = "adapterEntityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", dialect);  //"org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect"
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(dataSource());
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("com.textura.client.erp.database.model");
        lef.setPersistenceUnitName("adapterPersistenceUnit");
        lef.setJpaProperties(properties);
        lef.afterPropertiesSet();
        return lef.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "adapterTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }
}
```

**application.properties file in classpath**

```
# database configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/internal;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.schema=schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=data.sql
spring.datasource.initialize=false
#spring.datasource.initialize=true only for first time to create table, after that switch to false

# JPA. Hibernate
spring.jpa.database=H2
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=choose one of [create-drop, create, update, validate, none]
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true


# MS SQL Server 2008 datasource
adapter.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://some.ip.address:1433;databaseName=Remote
adapter.datasource.username=sa
adapter.datasource.password=password
adapter.datasource.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
```

After that, I'm seeing the GenerationType.IDENTITY works like charm

```
Hibernate: insert into invoice_header (ApprovalDate, ApproverUserName) values (?, ?)
```